# llblgen pro - change stored procedure parameter name during code gen

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, llblgenpro

I am using LLBLGEN Pro to generate a data layer...some of my stored procs have parameter name as "date"...so this is cauing a problem when I compile in VS2010...I have to go through the class and change the function parameters "date" to "[date]".

Is there a way to inject these changes in LLBLGEN Pro during code generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution in the designer, edit stored procedure and change parameter name.

Refer to [doc](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20designer/designer_addingspcalls.htm)